# password protecting amazon s3 download link in a django template

Tags: amazon-s3, django-templates

I have a django template which contains a link to a file stored on amazon s3. This template is an email to be sent automatically from the system. I want this link to be password protected. on clicking this link, the file on s3 in opened in browser without any authentication. I want the user to first log in to my django website and then the file is opened in the website.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks,
Ammara

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have the link in the email use a URL that goes to a view in your site, setup auth normally there, then have the s3 link available from some landing page behind auth on your site.

Just FYI tho: This is a really bad idea if any level of actual security is needed.